No Pylance hints after decorating a class (Python)
I have a question about Pylance hints after decorating a class. I have a useless minimal example:
class PrimaryModel():

    def print(self):
        print("I am invisible O.o")

def mydeco(cls: PrimaryModel):
    return cls

if __name__ == "__main__":

    @mydeco
    class User(PrimaryModel):
        pass

    alan = User()
    alan.print()    # no hints

The problem is alan.print method seems to be unknown in IDE (VS Code). (Code works fine)
Now I can fix it by explicit type declaration. Here, it hints well:
class PrimaryModel():

    def print(self):
        print("I am invisible O.o")

def mydeco(cls: PrimaryModel):
    return cls

if __name__ == "__main__":

    @mydeco
    class User(PrimaryModel):
        pass

    alan: PrimaryModel = User()
    alan.print()    # hints ok

But then, if I sublclass the User, again, no hints (uncommenting the decorator enables hints):
class PrimaryModel():

    def print(self):
        print("I am invisible O.o")

def mydeco(cls: PrimaryModel):
    return cls

if __name__ == "__main__":

    @mydeco
    class User(PrimaryModel):
        pass

    class Player(User):
        pass

    alan: PrimaryModel = Player()
    alan.print()    # no hints :'(

Where is the problem? Is it too complex for Pylance to solve the type? Why it does not hint even if I explicitly declare the type? Can it be solved somehow?
I tried explicit type declaration, checking runtime type. Just did not manage to make it work.

Did you add an explicit return type to mydeco?

You need an explicit return type on mydeco, and that should be constructed from a bound type variable.
class PrimaryModel():

    def print(self):
        print("I am invisible O.o")

def mydeco[T: Type[PrimaryModel]](cls: T) -> T:
    return cls

if __name__ == "__main__":

    @mydeco
    class User(PrimaryModel):
        pass

    class Player(User):
        pass

    alan: PrimaryModel = Player()

Previously, the static type of User was Any, which is compatible with PrimaryModel, but doesn't carry any information about the class. By correctly typing mydeco, the static type of User remains User itself.

Ok, thanks. That works. But I am quite unfamiliar with generics, so I have to look at it deeper. Thank you

I think you mean T: type[PrimaryModel] or (cls: type[T]) -> type[T]?

Yeah. I think the former would be preferable? Though I think the bound is unnecessary; it only limits what mydeco can be applied to, not what it does.

@InSync why should one specify Type[T]? T is already Type of class PrimaryModel, no? And that usage on type with lower “t” is allowed?

The (intended) argument is not an instance of PrimaryModel, but PrimaryModel itself (or a subclass). type was made generic in Python 3.9, with the subsequent deprecation of typing.Type.
